# Regular initial data

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, mathematical-physics, definition, differential-equations

I have a very basic question. What exactly is meant by "regular" initial data in general relativity? Does it mean smooth? at least $C^{2}$?

All literature on the subject just uses this term without exact explanation, so it seems that it's something very trivial, but I just wanted to know for sure.

Comment: With [Bianchi identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BianchiIdentities.html) it seems  better than the metric tensor would be, at least, 3 times differentiable, but I think that the standard is infinitely differentiable, so $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Could you include an example of where the term is being used so that we can have some context.  The answer to this could very well be context-dependent after all.

Comment: @joshphysics well,it's used literally in every book/paper. Some examples: [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.0949.pdf), on page 2 talks about "sufficiently regular" without explanation what it is, or another example [link](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/sfar.pdf)